# What built in Shader should be included on 2d platform (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, apk, shader

Current I have this built-in shader setting for 2D platform

[Built-in Shader Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hots3.jpg)

So what should I remove there so that I can build my APK very fast. Please help me.

Comment: Well...which of those shaders are you using?

Comment: Actually which is the default shader there? because that's the only thing i need

Comment: None of those are the standard shader.

Comment: @Draco18s oh thank you..